# How do you formulate Microsoft Excel "if" statement equivalent in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

The syntax of a simple Excel if statement is:

```
=IF(a1="a",b2,"")
```

This places the contents of cell b2 in the current cell if cell a1 contains the character "a". Otherwise the current cell is cleared.

How is this statement, for example, entered in Numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is the same as it is in Excel:

```
=IF(A1="a", B1,"")
```

For example:

[image: An example IF statement in Numbers]

And the results:

[image: The results of that IF statement in Numbers]